# Why SQL Server Management Studio 2005 showing Version 2012 on running 'select @@version'

Tags: sql-server, installation

I have installed SSMS 2012 before. Now I have need to install MSS 2005 on same machine.

I need to generate backup file which will be compatible with 2005 version.

But when I run

```
select @@version
```

command in SSMS 2005 it show me version 2012.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That query displays the version of MS SQL Server Database that your Management Studio connected to, not the version of the Management Studio itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your command

```
select  @@version
```

is being executed against the version of SQL Server you are connected to.  It has nothing to do with the version of SSMS you run the command from.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem- I was connecting to instance which was created for 2012.

server name I was entering- **COMPUTER_NAME**

I changed the server name to connect to a named instance and the problem is solved.

Server name I and entering now is - **COMPUTER_NAME\SQLExpress**

COMPUTER_NAME connects to default instance
COMPUTER_NAME\SQLExpress connects to named instance

Comment: Glad you have solved your issue, however, IMO, you should choose either @EricJ. or my answer as an accepted answer, right?